Extract components of tensor in xCoba to form a Differential equation
I am new to xCoba in Mathematica. Recently I try to extract the components of a result of tensor contraction to form a ODEs and use DSolve to get the general solutions.
In 3-dimension (chart $\tau, y,\phi$), I am manipulating like this
kernelLichuu = cd[\[Gamma]]@cd[-\[Gamma]]@h[-\[Mu], -\[Nu]] +  2 rt[-\[Mu], -\[Alpha], -\[Nu], -\[Sigma]] h[\[Alpha], \[Sigma]];
kernelLich = Head[kernelLichuu]

Here h is depend on 3 function f1, f2 and f3, which only depends on one of coordinate y.And then I want to let kernelLich be equal to zero, then will give me enough ODEs to determine the general solutions to f1[y],f2[y] and f3[y]
DSolve[{(kernelLich[{1, -nbtz}, {1, -nbtz}] /. {t[] -> 0}) == 0,
        (kernelLich[{2, -nbtz}, {1, -nbtz}] /. {t[] -> 0}) == 0,
        (kernelLich[{0, -nbtz}, {0, -nbtz}] /. {t[] -> 0}) == 0}, {f1[y[]], f2[y[]], f3[y[]]}, y[]]

But then I got the error Function::flpar: Parameter specifications {y} in Function[{y},0] should be a symbol or a list of symbols.
I tried by using /. to replace y[] to y, but also failed to get codes work. Thank you in advance for your help.
